# Git Not Able to Pull As Changes Done On Server Files

Tags: git, server, git-pull, pull

I have done from my local to server `git push`. Unfortunately before pull after i have made some changes on Server Files.

So it's not allowing me to Pull.

```
root@magento-dev-1:/var/www/html/magento# git pull
Updating 4d1729d..6e1c543
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        magento/app/code/Custome/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Actions.php
        magento/app/code/Custome/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/posts_index.xml
        magento/app/code/Custome/Module/view/frontend/templates/etrade/form.phtml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: read the message > Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: run `git stash` or `git commit`

Answer (score 2):

You have to commit your changes first or stash them.

```
git stash
```

This will put your modified changes aside and make your working directory clean. Later, after pull, you can reapply those changes with

```
git stash pop
```

This is what Git suggests you to do.

> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.